# A sudoku problem: Efficiently find or approximate probability distribution over chosen numbers at each index of an array with no repeats

Tags: algorithm, optimization, linear-algebra, probability, combinatorics

I'm looking for an efficient algorithm to generate or iteratively approximate a solution to the problem described below.

You are given an array of length N and a finite set of numbers S<sub>i</sub> for each index i of the array. Now, if we are to place a number from  S<sub>i</sub> at each index i to fill the entire array, while ensuring that the number is unique across the entire array; given all the possible arrays, what is the probability ditribution over each number at each index?

Here I give an example:
Assuming we have the following array of length 3 with each column representing  S<sub>i</sub> at the index of the column

4 4 4 
   2  2 
1  1  1

We will have the following possible arrays:

421 
412 
124 
142

And the following probability distribution: (over 1 2 4 at each index respectively)

0.5 0.25 0.25 
      0.5   0.5  
0.5 0.25 0.25

Brute forcing this problem is obviously doable but I have a gut feeling that there must be some more efficient algorithms for this.

The reason why I think so is due to the fact that one can derive the probability distribution from the set of all possibilities but not the other way around, so the distribution itself must contain less information then the set of all possibilities have. Therefore, I believe that we do not need to generate all possibilites just to obtain the probability distribution.

Hence, I am wondering if there is any smart matrix operation we could use for this problem or even fixed-point iteration/density evolution to approximate the end probability distribution? Some other potentially more efficient approaches to this problem are also appreciated.

(p.s. The reason why I am interested in this problem is because I wanted to generate probability distribution over candidate numbers for the empty cells in a sudoku and other sudoku-like games without a unique answers by only applying all the standard rules)

Comment: You basically need to compute a bunch of matrix [permanents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computing_the_permanent). There's an O(2^n poly(n))-time algorithm that will beat the pants off of the naive O(n!) algorithm, but for large n you're looking at an approximation.

Comment: If you are using this for a sudoku, do you only want to do this for one row/column/box? I.e. a maximum of 9 cells? Doing it for the whole sudoku is equivalent to solving it and there should only be one possibility.

Comment: Indeed I am only doing this for one row/column/box. The catch here is that I am not only doing it for a normal 9x9 sudoku but also for more general NxN cases and other sudoku-like games. Even for the classical 9x9 case, I am also interested in sudokus without a unique solution until more rules are applied.

Answer (score 0):

Sudoku is a combinatorial problem. It is easy to show that the probability of any independent cell is uniform (because you can relabel a configuration to put any number at a given position). The joint probabilities are more complicated.

If the game is partially filled you have constraints that will affect this distribution.

You must devise an algorithm to calculate the number of solutions from a given initial configuration. Then you compute the fraction of the total solutions are will have a specific value at the position of interest.

```
counts = {}
for i in range(1, 10):
  board[cell] = i;
  counts[i] = countSolutions(board);
prob = {i: counts[i] / sum(counts[i] for i in range(1, 10))}
```

The same approach works for joint probabilities but in some cases the number of possibilities may be too high.

Comment: Thanks for answering! However, this is what I assume to be a brute-force algorithm that is not very efficient. Also, although the motivation for solving this problem came from sudoku, I am more interested in the general case that could be applied to all sudoku-like games. For that matter, I would really appreciate something more sophiticated and efficient that probably involve the use of techniques such as density evolution or fixed point iteration.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. If you want a concrete solution I would suggest to ask a question based on a [mwe](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).